# "FileNotFoundError: libtorchaudio.pyd Not Found Error When Using PyTorchAudio Library - PyCharm, Windows"

Tags: python, pytorch

I am a Windows user and I want to use the pytrochaudio library but
PyCharm gives this error

> (FileNotFoundError: Could not find module ‘C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\project_pytorch\venv\pythonProject36\venv\Lib\site-packages\torchaudio\lib\libtorchaudio.pyd’ . Try using the full path with constructor syntax.).

What do you think could be the reason for this and how can it be fixed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was raised in https://github.com/pytorch/audio/issues/2726 and https://github.com/pytorch/audio/issues/3282. This appears to be caused by a missing `cudart64_110.dll`. To fix this, add `cudart64_110.dll` to conda env. Please look at the links I included for more information.